# Compile c preprocessor output

Tags: c-preprocessor

I know you can use cpp directly or call it through gcc -E to generate preprocessor output for an input file.

But how can I, given such an output file, compile it to object code or compile it and link it into an executable image?

Edit:
the whole problem apparently was that I wasn't giving the file that I redirected cpp's output to a .c extension, and gcc didn't like it.

Comment: I am kinda lost. How is such an output file not C code? Do you mind giving a [mcve]?

Comment: I edited it to include the exact case

Comment: I find it hard to believe that's the "exact case" since your supposed command line refers to `out_preprocessed` and the error message refers to `outprep`.

Comment: The extension of the preprocessed file needs to be `.c` -- no extension leads to "file format not recognized".

Comment: @AKX I was in a hurry and used some very short stupid filenames, so I tried to modify them here to make them clearer. The problem wasn't with that. The problem is, like you pointed out and I understood just seconds before, the extension. This is news to me, that the extension actually MUST be .c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I, given such an output file, compile it to object code or compile it and link it into an executable image?

Normally, just like with any other source file, pass it to `gcc`.

```
cpp input_file > output_file.c
gcc output_file.c
./a.out
```